# How to have vim always call a function after any yank

Tags: vim

Is there a way to have vim always call a defined function after any yanking operation? Doing something like `nnoremap y y:function<CR>` results in abnormal behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TextYankPost` event will be triggered after text has been yanked or deleted. See `:h TextYankPost` for more help.

```
augroup Example
    autocmd!
    autocmd TextYankPost * if v:event.operator ==# 'y' | call somefunction() | endif
augroup END
```

I know that [vim-highlightedyank](https://github.com/machakann/vim-highlightedyank) uses the `TextYankPost` event and maybe a place to look for inspiration.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks so much.